# Parallelogram Rule and Head to Tail Rule

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calc

Here's my current MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{>=stealth}
\colorlet{veccol}{green!45!black}
\tikzstyle{vector}=[->,very thick,veccol]

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[<->] (0,0)--(5.5,0) node[right]{$x$};
      \draw[<->] (0,0)--(0,5.5) node[above]{$y$};

      \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
      \coordinate (A) at (125:5);
      \coordinate (B) at (0:4);
      \coordinate (A+B) at ($(A)+(B)$);

      \draw[vector,blue] (0,0)--(A) node[midway,left] {$\vec{x}$};
      \draw[vector,red] (0,0)--(B) node[midway,above] {$\vec{y}$};

      \draw[vector,thin,dashed] (A)--(A+B);
      \draw[vector,thin,dashed] (B)--(A+B);

      \draw[vector,purple] (O)--(A+B) node[above,rotate=-60] {$\vec{x}+\vec{y}$};
      \draw[rotate=180] (O)--(A+B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which produces this pdf:

[image]

Here's the issue. I'm always writing this code out. I have it in 10+ places. Is there a  way that I can create something like a function, feed it the two (or more) vectors using polar coordinates, and graphs it like this?

Also, how would I draw using the same exact vectors using the head-to-tail rule instead of the parallelogram rule? Would it also be possible to create some sort of reusable function like the question from above, but use it for the head-to-tail rule instead of the parallelogram rule?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the parallelogram part:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\parallelogramRule}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=1pt,>=stealth]
        \draw[<->] (0,0)--(5.5,0) node[right]{$x$};
        \draw[<->] (0,0)--(0,5.5) node[above]{$y$};
        
        \tikzstyle{vector label} = [midway,fill=white,sloped]
        \tikzstyle{vector}=[->,very thick]
        \tikzstyle{construction} = [->,thin,dashed,draw=green!45!black]
        
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (A) at (#1);
        \coordinate (B) at (#2);
        \coordinate (A+B) at ($(A)+(B)$);
        
        \draw[vector,blue] (O)--(A) node[vector label] {$\vec{x}$};
        \draw[vector,red] (O)--(B) node[vector label] {$\vec{y}$};
        
        \draw[construction] (A)--(A+B);
        \draw[construction] (B)--(A+B);
        
        \draw[vector,purple] (O)--(A+B) node[vector label] {$\vec{x}+\vec{y}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \parallelogramRule{30:5}{0:4}%
        \parallelogramRule{130:2}{90:2}%
        \parallelogramRule{130:4}{-10:2}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Implementing the head-to-tail rule is simple, just replace the addition by subtraction and change the label of the resultant vector.

**Edit**

For adding multiple vectors

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\multipleVecAdd}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt]
        \tikzstyle{vector}=[->,very thick,blue]
        \tikzstyle{vector label} = [midway,fill=white,sloped]
        \tikzstyle{resultant}=[->,very thick,red]
        
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
        \draw [->] (O) -- (4,0) node [right] {$x$};
        \draw [->] (O) -- (0,4) node [right] {$y$};
        
        \setsepchar{;}
        \readlist*{\veclist}{#1}
        \coordinate (resultant) at (O);
        \foreach \i in {1,2,...,\veclistlen}{%
            \coordinate (vec\i) at (\veclist[\i]);
            \draw [vector] (O) -- (vec\i) node [vector label] {$\vec{v}_\i$};
            \coordinate (resultant) at ($(resultant)+(vec\i)$);
        }
        \draw [resultant] (O) -- (resultant) node [vector label] {resultant};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \multipleVecAdd{1,1;-2,3;4,1;4,-2;-1,-4}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit 2**

Following suggestions of Qrrbrbirlbel and SebGlav, using `tikzset` and `\pgffor` directly.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\multipleVecAdd}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt]
        \tikzset{%
            vector/.style={->,very thick,blue},
            vector label/.style={midway,fill=white,sloped},
            resultant/.style={->,very thick,red}
        }
        
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
        \draw [->] (O) -- (4,0) node [right] {$x$};
        \draw [->] (O) -- (0,4) node [above] {$y$};
        
        \coordinate (resultant) at (O);
        \foreach \vecPos [count=\vecId] in {#1}{%
            \draw [vector] (O) -- \vecPos node [vector label] {$\vec{v}_\vecId$};
            \draw (resultant) +\vecPos coordinate (resultant);
        }
        \draw [resultant] (O) -- (resultant) node [vector label] {resultant};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \multipleVecAdd{(1,1),(-2,3),(4,1),(4,-2),(-1,-4)}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: how would I make this work for n number of vectors?

Comment: Do you mean you wish to add n number of vectors?

Comment: If you use `(1, 1), (-2, 3), …` (parentheses around the coordinates), you can use it directly as a list for `\foreach`. See [Special handling of pairs.](https://tikz.dev/pgffor#\foreach)

Comment: Use of `tikzstyle` is deprecated. You should use `tikzset` instead.